# SQL Query : Cannot create view due to error #1349 : Help to restructure query

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1349

I using a query that selects a check type "checks" and looks in the log file to find the most recent log entry referencing this check.

```
SELECT checks.*, logs.last_completed_on, logs.completed_by
    FROM checks INNER JOIN 
         (
             SELECT check_id, MAX(completed_on) AS last_completed_on,
             completed_by FROM checks_log GROUP BY check_id
          ) logs    
ON checks.id = logs.check_id
```

This query works but i need to create a view for it. This is the first time I've used views so i don't know a lot about them but i read that its not possible with this type of query...

My question is whether there was a way to restructure it in any way?

I guess another solution would be to call this query on a specific check id for every row in a table? It sounds bad practice though... and slow, but i'm not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view in MySQL cannot handle subqueries in the `from` clause.  So, you will need somewhat different logic.

This version should work:

```
SELECT c.*, cl.completed_on as last_completed_on, cl.completed_by
FROM checks c INNER JOIN 
     checks_log cl
     ON c.check_id = cl.check_id
WHERE cl.completed_on = (SELECT MAX(cl2.completed_on)
                         FROM checks_log cl2 
                         WHERE cl2.check_id = cl.check_id
                        );
```

MySQL does allow subqueries in the `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses, so this should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the query is working correctly you can create a view from it. 
CREATE VIEW {insertnamehere} as 
(insertyourqueryhere) 
Try with and without the parenthesis. I don't know what tool you're using*